# Mac Mini 2012 - dual band bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

does anyone know what the radio is in the mac mini late 2012? The only detail I can find is that it is 4.0, but I can't find out if it is dual-band capable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answers your question but here:

**Single-Chip Bluetooth® 4.0 HCI Solution with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) Support**

*The Broadcom BCM20702 is a single-chip Bluetooth processor with a high performance integrated 2.4-GHz RF transceiver. It is fully compliant with Bluetooth 4.0 and all prior standard features. The BCM20702 offers unmatched integration, including on-board memory for a very small footprint and low cost of implementing a Bluetooth system.*

Which i got from *http://www.broadcom.com/products/Bluetooth/Bluetooth-RF-Silicon-and-Software-Solutions/BCM20702*.
I got this from *ifixit*'s Mac Mini Late 2012 teardown.